# Mask a subdomain as subfolder and allow access from only from the folder URL

Tags: url, subdomain, subdirectory

I have `serviceX.example.com` and I don't want to move everything, I want to mask the URL so visitors and search engines see `example.com/serviceX` instead of the original/real location.

I don't want `serviceX.example.com` to be accessible except from the masked URL with the subfolder.

The website is on a Linux server with Plesk installed on it.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to move everything?   Masking doesn't make the content inaccessible from the true URL, and as far as I know it can't.    Is moving everything really too hard?

Comment: Where does `serviceX.example.com` point to on the filesystem in relation to `example.com`?